# Using causative verb "get" correctly

Tags: grammar, verbs, causatives, causative-get

Causative verbs to me are: *make*, *let*, *have*, *help* and *get*.

They all get a direct object and the verb after the object (if it's a full-infinitive) comes in the bare infinitive form. It's correct for all of them except "get".

For example, the structure below is not correct.
*subject + get (in any tense or person) someone/something + bare infinitive*

That is, *get* has no specific rule as in other ordinary verbs but has the meaning of causing in its causative form sentence.

Do you, too, think like above?

Comment: You asked the same question on another forum under the name of KhoshtipMan. What is it that you still don't understand?

Comment: Did you read the next question there please?

Comment: Causative "get" takes a _to_-infinitival complement, if that's what you're asking

Comment: So the structure I mentioned in the questions's body above cannot be correct, yeah?

Comment: I meant this structure: **subject + get (in any tense or person) someone/something + bare infinitive**.

Comment: It's wrong insofar as causative "get" takes a _to_-infinitival complement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62574/discussion-between-abbasi-and-billj).

Comment: _"I got him to quit"_ is possible. _"I got him quit"_ is impossible. **But** _"I made him to quit"_ is impossible. _"I made him quit"_ is possible.

Comment: +1 for both of you. And I think I wrote the same thing as your opinion, in the question. :)

Comment: _Help_ can take either the marked or bare infinitive, and your question lacks any mention of that distinction.

Comment: I use BrE, and in it I suppose the bare infinitive form is mostly used for *help*.